# I want the sql IN operator to return null when record is not found

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get `null` value for each element if there is no match in the `in` operator value, *e.g.*

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In such a case I want to get `null` value in case `IN` operator value does not exists, *e.g.* for

```
IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I want return value as

> 'ABC', null, 'XYZ', null, null

Currently it just returns

> 'ABC', 'XYZ'

Comment: In which table is `user_id`?

Comment: in the second table table2

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Have you ever heard about `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @AlessioCantarella I have just edited my question to a simple example without any joins. Please check

Comment: @Raj without joins your question has no sense at all. You should use `LEFT JOIN` towards the second table to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just create helper table with all values:

```
create table helpTable (uid int);
insert into helpTable values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

and then `left join` it and use `case` statement to determine if there should be displayed `name` when there's corresponding value (not `null`):

```
SELECT case when ht.uid is not null then name end `name`
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN helpTable ht ON t.id = ht.uid;
```

After you are done, `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS helpTable;`.

If you don't want to create table, you could do this (but I am not 100% sure that it'll work):

```
SELECT case when ht.uid is not null then name end `name`
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN (
    select 1 `uid`
    union all
    select 2
    union all
    select 3
    union all
    select 4
    union all
    select 5
) ht ON t.id = ht.uid;
```

Comment: is there any possibility without creating the table ?

Comment: @Raj Try second version :)

Comment: I think you have the left join reversed.

Comment: @BillKarwin No, it needs to be left joined to the table, this way in case of no match there will be `NULL` as corresponding value.

Comment: you want all the rows from helptable returned, and a row with null where there is a row in helptable but no matching row in table t, right? The helptable has all the possible values. The table t may have gaps where some values in helptable have no match. So you need helptable on the left side of the `LEFT JOIN`. Or else you can change the join to a `RIGHT JOIN` and keep helptable on the right side.

Comment: @BillKarwin No, you got it exactly opposite :) that's why you think it should be `right join` :)

Answer (score 1):

This predicate:

```
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Can only be applied to rows that exist in the table. That's how the `WHERE` clause works, it is evaluated for rows that exist, and if the conditions are true, that row is included in the result set of the query.

A predicate cannot invent new rows that don't exist in your table.

So no, you can't use `IN ( )` to insert NULL rows where the id is missing in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary table, e.g.:

```
create tmp_table (name varchar2(32);
```

and use this pl/sql procedure:

```
declare
name_tmp varchar2(32);
for i in (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) loop
SELECT name name_tmp into FROM table id=i.id;
exception when no_data_found then name_tmp := null; end;
insert into tmp_table (name) values (name_tmp) ;
end loop; 
end;
```